# Intersection of key values between 2 different collections in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have 2 collections: `bookings` and `timeslots`.

`models/booking.js:`

```
var mongoose = require ('../config/db');
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var bookingSchema = new Schema({
    start: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    end: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    date: {
        type: Date,
        required: true,
        default: Date.now
    }
});
```

`models/time_slot.js:`

```
var mongoose = require ('../config/db');
var Schema = require('mongoose').Schema;
var ObjectId = Schema.ObjectId;

var timeSlotSchema = new Schema({
  start: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  end: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
    default: Time.Today
  },
  enabled: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true,
  },
  pickup: {
    type: Boolean,
    required: true,
    default: true,
  }
});
```

Both have a field `start` in common. I would like to be able to get the entries from the collection `timeslots` in which the value of `start` has occurred in `bookings`.

I have tried:

`controllers/time_slot.js:`

```
var timeSlotModel = require('../models/time_slot').model;
var Booking = require('./booking');

Booking.getBookings({}, function(err, bookings) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    timeSlotModel.find({start: bookings.start}, function(err, slots) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        return next(null, slots);
      }
    }
}
```

But that doesn't work, unsurprisingly, and I get the error:

```
MongooseError: Cast to number failed for value "undefined" at path "start"
```

Comment: can you show us also `getBookings` method?

Comment: is bookings an array? because that way .start would not be a field

Comment: Could you show us the `TimeSlot` model?

Comment: @ZeMoon I have added both models. @drinchev `getBookings` is a standard read function that uses the mongoose `model.find({})` to get all bookings.
@Lucas Katayama no, it's a model.

Comment: If you have `model.find({})` as `getBookings` it will return an array.

Comment: @drinchev I printed `bookings` and you sir are correct. I can use a nested loop to compare the values of the `start` field for each `timeslot`.. or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
Booking.getBookings({}, function(err, bookings) {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {

    // build array with unique "start" values from bookings
    var starts = bookings
      .map(booking => booking.start)
      .filter((val, i, self) => self.indexOf(val) === i)

    // find by these start values
    var query = {start: {$in: starts}}

    timeSlotModel.find(query, function(err, slots) {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        return next(null, slots);
      }
    }
}
```